# I have rows of strings in the MongoDB format in a specific column in the .csv file How do I convert it into dataframe?

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, csv, dataframe

The rows int the column are of type:
{ "a" : "1", "b" : "2" }, { "a" : "1", "b" : "2", "c": "3" }, etc.
How do I convert it into a dataframe with appropriate labels of a, b, c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need convert `strings` to `dict`s by `json.loads` and then call `DataFrame` contructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['{ "a" : "1", "b" : "2" }', 
                         '{ "a" : "1", "b" : "2", "c": "3" }']})

df = pd.DataFrame(df['a'].apply(pd.io.json.loads).values.tolist())

print (df)
   a  b    c
0  1  2  NaN
1  1  2    3
```

Comment: Why not just `pd.DataFrame(a)`?

Comment: becuse it is only sample df.

Comment: Well maybe I don't understand the question then :)

Comment: ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7f9f3537f198>
I am facing this error

Comment: @VedangMandhana - How working `df = pd.DataFrame(df['a'].apply(pd.io.json.loads).values.tolist())` ?